# Adding list python

Tags: python, list

Help! What do I have to change so that it comes out like this?

```
[('Mavis', 3), ('Ethel', 1), ('Rick', 2), ('Joseph', 5), ('Louis', 4)]
```

Right now, with my code, it comes out like this.

```
bots_status = [(bot_one_info) + (bot_two_info) + (bot_three_info) + (bot_four_info) + (bot_five_info)]
```

> [('Mavis', 3, 'Ethel', 1, 'Rick', 2, 'Joseph', 5, 'Louis', 4)]

Comment: at least, show `bot_one_info` value

Comment: bot_one_info would be ('Mavis', 3)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place commas instead of + signs between your bots.
If working with a variable amount of entries, initialize an array and add to it using append.

```
bots_status = []
for bot_info in bot_infos:
    bots_status.append(bot_info)
```

Comment: I don’t understand the purpose of this loop. If you already have the `bot_infos` as a list, why would you loop over them to add the items to another list…? (And it’s somewhat apparent that OP does *not* have the items as a list, otherwise this question would not exist.)

Comment: This was for the purpose of demonstration. OP could have wanted to iterate bot objects instead of strings.

Nonetheless, I'll keep in mind to make that clearer in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the plusses (`+`) by commas (`,`) to make this a list of tuples instead of a list of one concatenated tuple:

```
bots_status = [bot_one_info, bot_two_info, bot_three_info, bot_four_info, bot_five_info]
```

Since your `bot_x_info` variables already are tuples, you also don’t need to use parentheses around the names (those don’t do anything).

---

The problem with your code was that you were using `+` on the tuples. The add operator concatenates tuples to a single one:

```
>>> (1, 2) + (3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

That’s why you ended up with one giant tuple in your list.

What you wanted is have each tuple as a separate item in the list, so you just need to create a list from those. Just like you would do `[1, 2, 3]` to create a list with three items, using a comma to separate each item, you also do this with other values, e.g. tuples in your case.

Comment: can you have a look at my first statement in my answer please, I am having the contradiction here. Help me understand.

Comment: @Bhansa I am not sure what you are asking. Using `+` on tuples will concatenate the tuples (making it a single one with all values combined). Using a comma will make each tuple a separate item in your list.

Comment: and OP wants to have a list of single tuple right ? so `+` satisfies the condition here, why `,` then ? Hope you understand.

Comment: @Bhansa You have it backwards there; OP is currently using `+` in their approach but he actually wants to have each tuple as a separate item in the list. (The first line in the question is what he wants; the last line is what he currently has with his code)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:

```
bot_one_info = ('Mavis', 3)
bot_two_info = ('Mavi', 3)
```

If you use `+`

```
lis = [bot_one_info + bot_two_info]
print lis
#Output 
[('Mavis', 3, 'Mavi', 3)]
```

But if you use `,`

```
lis = [bot_one_info,bot_two_info]
print lis 
#Output
[('Mavis', 3), ('Mavi', 3)]
```

You can use here `,` instead of `+`.

Comment: OP wants it the other way around.

Comment: yea I want the other way around